# ActionText: Link to attachment instead of preview

Tags: trix, actiontext

Is there a way for Trix editor (or ActionText) to display a link of the file attached so people could download it instead of showing a preview of the file? My example attachment is a PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit it in the `_blob.html.erb` file,
for example:

```rb
<span class="attachment__download"><%= link_to blob.filename, rails_blob_path(blob) %></span>
<span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
```

Because action text will use this `_blob.html.erb` file for rendering the attachment file you upload, you can do anything in here with object `blob` (ActiveStorage::Blob)

For more information

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html